# Mongodb greater than query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an `employee` collection like this

```
Company.            Ceo.       Employees
Sdr.                Siva.      1-200
Datamatica.         Durga.     200-400
Big.                Mouli.     50-100
```

After using

```
db.employee.find({Employees : {$gte : 200}})
```

I don't get any data. The `Employees` field type is a string.

Comment: share more collection info.

Comment: change Employees field type to Number

Comment: you cant make a range request on a string field. Split your Employees field into EmployeesFrom(Number) and EmployeesTo(Number) and query each field for $gte, $lte etc.

Comment: Can I split one field into 2 fields directly because I am having millions of Records                                             After I changed character  string to number I am not getting any result

Answer (score 18):

As japrescott stated, you should split the `Employees`field into two separate fields (employees_from, employees_to) of type `Number` and then query like this:

```
db.employee.find({employees_from : {$gte : 200}})
```

For migration you could use mongo's [map reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) to split the current `Employees` into two separate field and add these to your documents. Afterwards you can delete the `Employees` field.